# undo button actions?

Tags: android

I have some buttons and when click on each of them, the button do the following:

```
public TextView CurrentPosW(){

    TextView wordletters[] = {wordLetter1, wordLetter2, wordLetter3,
            wordLetter4, wordLetter5, wordLetter6, wordLetter7};

    TextView currentPos = null;
    for(int i=0; i<wordletters.length; i++){
    if(!wordletters[i].getText().toString().equals(("*")) && wordletters[i].getText().toString().equals("")){       
        currentPos = wordletters[i];
        return currentPos;
        }
    }
    return null;
```

The CurrentPos() method checks 7 different textviews and set the text to the first empty textview every time is called, and called from every of the 7 buttons. 
Also some of the buttons may have the same texts.
I want to be able, by clicking on a textview, to undo the action for this textview. 
Let's say that the above 5th buttons have set the text of 3rd textview. So when this textview clicked I want to:
-reinable the button
-set it again clickable
-empty the text of this textview
So basically I want to undo the actions of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To undo this you have to save the last action somehow. after a click on a textview you have to know which action was made last time for this view. For this you need to know which button updated this specific textview last time.

To store the sate you can do many things. For example you can store the the id of a textview's id and the button's id which have changed it last time and store it as key value pair. Or you can set sequential value to textview from 0 to n and in a 1d array just store the data as the textview's assigned number as index and button's as value. Or you can use other methods. But the key thing is you have to store the info that for a specific textview which button has changed it last time.

If you know the value mentioned above then you can just undo the settings easily.

As I have mentioned there might be so many other ways to do that so you can think of other methods. And if I misunderstood your problem please correct me.

Comment: I think you understand correct. Can you please post an example for the id way? Also have in mind that stored values must updated, when the buttons being clickable again, and the pairs will be different.

Answer (score 1):

If you setClickable(false) then you can't click on that textview. So maybe a solution would be to add an Undo button and store the actions you did in an ArrayList, or some kind of stack.

Comment: The setClickable(false) is for the button not the textview.

Answer (score 0):

**

### UPDATE and ask for additional Help

**
I've made some progress, I made sorter the method I use to dynamicaly add Text to the Textviews by the clicks of buttons.
I used a sequence like solution for solving the above problem, but doesn't work as I wanted. I made an array list to sort the sequence of buttons clicks:

```
ArrayList<TextView> letterList = new ArrayList<TextView>();
```

(Yes, there are textviews also, but I call them buttons to seperate them from the other letters group).

Then I add the corresponding view to the arraylist when the button clicked with this code:

```
if(letterList.size() < 8 && !letterList.contains(randomLetter1))
        letterList.add(randomLetter1);
```

Now on textviews I use the list to get the button's view(textview in fact):

```
String wLetter = wordLetter1.getText().toString();
        if(wLetter.equals(letterList.get(0).toString()))
            letterList.get(0).setText(wLetter);
            letterList.get(0).setClickable(true);
            letterList.get(0).setEnabled(true);
            wordLetter1.setText("");
```

Multiply the above for all 7 Textviews and buttons.
This approach works fine until a position change. I mean that if for example I push the 1st, 3rd and 6th button with this order, these 3 button clicks file the first 3 textviews. If I click now on the 2nd textview the letter on this textview returns back to button(in fact this button becames enable an clickable again) and the position clears. Now if push the 4th button for eg, this gets the 2nd cleared position, and the problems start.
This happens because the created  pair of textview/button, never updates. So if the 3rd button link with the first textview, this link doesn't change if at the second click on 3rd button which now takes the position of the 3rd textview. 
But I want this link to be updated. I hope that you can understand the problem from above discription.

So do you think that this can be done by iprove the above solution, or must to follow a completely different road? Please try to include some code on your answer related to my code, to be more easy to understand, because I'm quite new to developing without any related studies and trying to read and learn alone.

Answer (score 0):

**Another Update with the solution I found**

I coundn't find a solution with the above way(save the sequence of clicked buttons to a list), so I tried a different approcach.
This time I used the clickable/enabled properties of buttons, by a method which return the disabled/non clickable buttons:

```
public List<TextView> getFreePos(){
TextView[] randomletters = {randomLetter1, randomLetter2, randomLetter3,
        randomLetter4, randomLetter5, randomLetter6, randomLetter7};
int i;
for( i=0; i<randomletters.length; i++){
if(randomletters[i].isClickable()== false){
    clickable.add(randomletters[i]);
}
}   
return clickable;
}
```

Then using it on each textview I check if the text of text view is equal to the first list' s object:

```
String wLetter = wordLetter1.getText().toString();          
        if(isEmpty(wordLetter1)){
        getFreePos().clear();
        getFreePos();           
        if(clickable.get(0).getText().toString().equals(wLetter)){
            clickable.get(0).setText(wLetter);
            clickable.get(0).setClickable(true);
            clickable.get(0).setEnabled(true);
        }
        else if(clickable.get(1).getText().toString().equals(wLetter)){
            clickable.get(1).setText(wLetter);
            clickable.get(1).setClickable(true);
            clickable.get(1).setEnabled(true);
        }
        else if (clickable.get(2).getText().toString().equals(wLetter)){
            clickable.get(2).setText(wLetter);
            clickable.get(2).setClickable(true);
            clickable.get(2).setEnabled(true);
        }
        else if (clickable.get(3).getText().toString().equals(wLetter)){
            clickable.get(3).setText(wLetter);
            clickable.get(3).setClickable(true);
            clickable.get(3).setEnabled(true);
        }
        else if (clickable.get(4).getText().toString().equals(wLetter)){
            clickable.get(4).setText(wLetter);
            clickable.get(4).setClickable(true);
            clickable.get(4).setEnabled(true);
        }
        else if (clickable.get(5).getText().toString().equals(wLetter)){
            clickable.get(5).setText(wLetter);
            clickable.get(5).setClickable(true);
            clickable.get(5).setEnabled(true);
        }
        else if (clickable.get(6).getText().toString().equals(wLetter)){
            clickable.get(6).setText(wLetter);
            clickable.get(6).setClickable(true);
            clickable.get(6).setEnabled(true);
        }
        }
        wordLetter1.setText("");
```

This way working fine, but I couldn't find a way to avoid all those if statements(the above code multiplied by 7).
I've tried to use a for loop, like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<clickable.size(); i++){
            if (wLetter.equals(clickable.get(i).getText().toString()))
        clickable.get(i).setText(wLetter);
        clickable.get(i).setEnabled(true);
        clickable.get(i).setClickable(true);
        wordLetter3.setText("");
        break;
```

and also to use switch cases instead of if statements, but both didn't work as expected. I had some index out of bounds errors(which didn't happen every time) and the problems with wrong buttons enabled and changed to wrong Letters.
So in conclusion, only the above if/else if way works as expected. I would be nice if the code could be shorten and more compact. Any thoughts/ideas?